# Capturing traffic in Selenium

Tags: python, http, post, selenium

I am capturing network traffic on Selenium objects on the HTTP post requests I am making. Although JSON string returned has the request headers, the body(params) of the post message is never captured.

Heres my code,

```
host = "localhost"
port = "4444"
browser = r"*pifirefox"
sel = selenium(host, port, browser, url)
.
.
.....Submit action
postRequest = sel.captureNetworkTraffic('json')
```

postRequest has,

```
[{
  "statusCode":200,
  "method":"POST",
  "url":"http://.................",
  "bytes":97567,
  "start":"2011-12-02T17:42:04.719-0500",
  "end":"2011-12-02T17:42:05.044-0500",
  "timeInMillis":325,
  "requestHeaders":[{
      "name":"Host",
      "value":"......................."
    },{
      "name":"User-Agent",
      "value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1"
    },{
      "name":"Accept",
      "value":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
    },{
      "name":"Accept-Language",
      "value":"en-us,en;q=0.5"
    },{
      "name":"Accept-Encoding",
      "value":"gzip, deflate"
    },{
      "name":"Accept-Charset",
      "value":"ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
    },{
      "name":"Proxy-Connection",
      "value":"keep-alive"
    },{
      "name":"Referer",
      "value":"...................."
    },{
      "name":"Cookie",
      "value":"...................."
    },{
      "name":"X-Requested-With",
      "value":"XMLHttpRequest"
    },{
      "name":"X-MicrosoftAjax",
      "value":"Delta=true"
    },{
      "name":"Cache-Control",
      "value":"no-cache, no-cache"
    },{
      "name":"Content-Type",
      "value":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
    },{
      "name":"Content-Length",
      "value":"10734"
    },{
      "name":"Pragma",
      "value":"no-cache"
  }],
  "responseHeaders":[{
      "name":"Date",
      "value":"Fri, 02 Dec 2011 22:42:05 GMT"
    },{
      "name":"Server",
      "value":"Microsoft-IIS/6.0"
    },{
      "name":"Cache-Control",
      "value":"private"
    },{
      "name":"Content-Type",
      "value":"text/plain; charset=utf-8"
    },{
      "name":"Content-Length",
      "value":"97567"
    },{
      "name":"X-Powered-By",
      "value":"ASP.NET"
    },{
      "name":"Via",
      "value":"1.1 (jetty)"
    },{
      "name":"X-AspNet-Version",
      "value":"4.0.30319"
  }]
}]
```

I am trying to imitate the Post request, but without the body(params), its incomplete. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the request or response body with Selenium - it only captures headers.  Try [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) if you're running on Windows.

Comment: thanks, will check out Fiddler2, although the site would be hosted on unix.

Comment: Fiddler runs on the client machine, and I see your User-Agent string says your client is on Windows, so you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

When selenium gives you the request headers, they have the information to craft a PyCurl or urllib request that fetches the response bodies.

For me this was as easy as running the following regex to rip out the urls, and then using 
curl to fetch them.

```
urls = re.finditer('\n  "url":"(.*)",', sel.captureNetworkTraffic('json'))
```

a regex was used since some of the responses had embedded json causing json.loads to blow up :(. There is some additional effort if the parameters are all in the response header instead of the url.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I may need more information about what you are trying to accomplish and why you chose selenium.

The only thing I can think of is piping the output of [tshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) or something similar into your python program.  I suppose there are also pcap readers, but I have no experience with these.  I briefly searched for a python network monitoring api, but had no such luck.

Comment: thanks, am scrapping sites with AJAX and Javascript enabled elements, hence Selenium. Also need to mimic a post request on the target sites to deeply connect to one of their pages. For this was crawling using Selenium, capture the Post request on the target page and then with httplib create the same request from my site.                                                                                       For example, on kayak.com, from the search results, once you make a selection it jumps to the checkout page of the airline's site. Trying to do the same, any suggestions to do this?

Comment: Are you translating the post requests you record to httplib by hand or programmatically?

Comment: Programmatically, was trying to crawl and then capture using Selenium, but if you know of a better way.

Comment: Thanks Derek, giving tshark a try, have captured network traffic using wireshark, needed a reader for the pcap file, wireshark seems to truncate the strings over a limit.