# Webscraping using Selenium and Python: Capture JSON body

Tags: python, ajax, json, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a webpage that has some AJAX running in the background. Using python and Selenium, I've gotten as far as loading the webpage, entering data into a form, clicking submit and waiting. At this point I'm trying to catch the JSON-formatted data that's retured, however [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363752/capturing-traffic-in-selenium) article suggests getting the JSON body out isn't possible. I've tried to look into the Selenium code myself to get it to return everything, but  I haven't had much luck. Any one out there who has encountered a similar problem and has a suggestion on how to solve it? I don't HAVE to use selenium (or python for that matter)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should be able to get the JSON directly.
The JSON is located [here](http://www.celebritycruises.com/search/loadSearchJSON.do?_=1364121769879&isWidget=false&dest=ANY&sailStartDate=ANY&sailEndDate=ANY&ship=ANY&port=ANY&duration=ANY&includeAdjascentPorts=Y&promoid=&promoType=&promotionTypeId=&priceProgram=&sortBy=4&startRow=0&count=10&cruiseType=CO&cruiseInt=Y&isCrieriaExcluded=false). You can use firefox with firebug to inspect the XHR requests to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I do this by looking at the ajax call the website is doing (in the source). This is usually a POST (sometimes a GET). Then I cURL (PHP) or urllib2 (Python) that URL + sending the needed data. This returns the body, including the JSON for me.

Comment: I'd love to do it that way, but the website uses JQuery so that's why I'm doing it using Selenium in the first place. Have you come across a scenario like that?

Comment: This is easy enough to do. You can inject some javascript to expose the JSON if need be. However it is on a case by case basis. If you can post your url it would be easier to comment further.

Comment: @user1609452 Sure thing! URL is below. I'm trying to extract dates and prices. As you can see, the page loads for a while. Using Firebug I can see the JSON load in, and that's what I'm trying to capture. I was thinking this shouldn't be too hard to do... http://www.celebritycruises.com/search/vacationSearchResults.do?wuc=USA#isWidget=false&dest=ANY&sailStartDate=ANY&sailEndDate=ANY&ship=ANY&port=ANY&duration=ANY&includeAdjascentPorts=Y&promoid=&promoType=&promotionTypeId=&priceProgram=&sortBy=4&startRow=0&count=10&cruiseType=CO&cruiseInt=Y&isCrieriaExcluded=false